# Nhibernate bag with bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, collections, bindingsource

I'm using a bindingsource to fill a form from Nhibernate list:

```
public class Customer{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set;}
}

bindingSourceCustomer.DataSource = session.Query<Customer>().ToList();
bindingSourceOrder.DataSource = bindingSourceCustomer;
bindingSourceOrder.DataMember = "Orders";
```

now when I call

```
bindingSourceOrder.AddNew();
```

an exception is thrown:

> The value "System.Object" is not of type "Model.Order" and cannot be
>   used in this generic collection.

Now I changed the first line to:

```
bindingSourceCustomer.DataSource = session.Query<Customer>().Select(customer => 
    { 
      customer.Orders = customer.Orders.ToList(); 
      return customer;
    })
    .ToList();
```

it worked, the reason why, is because Nhibernate uses the PersistentBag as an implementation of IList, which apparently doesn't work well with binding source (As far as I see).

Any suggestion either how to make Nhibernate return List class, or how to solve the problem with binding source?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the BindingSource is unable to discover the list type:
NHibernate's persistent bag has not the ITypedList interface nor the Indexer Property public.
You need to replace NHibernate CollectionTypeFactory with a custom one, before adding mappings.
I attach my implementation:

PersistentGenericBag:

```
public class EnhancedPersistentGenericBag<T> : PersistentGenericBag<T> , ITypedList
{
        public EnhancedPersistentGenericBag(ISessionImplementor session, ICollection<T> coll) : base(session, coll) { }

        public EnhancedPersistentGenericBag(ISessionImplementor session) : base(session) { }

        public EnhancedPersistentGenericBag() { }

        public new T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (T)base[index];
            }
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return GetType().Name; }

        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

---

CollectionTypeFactory:

```
public class EnhancedCollectionTypeFactory : DefaultCollectionTypeFactory
{


    public override CollectionType Bag<T>(string role, string propertyRef, bool embedded)
    {

         return  new EnhancedGenericBagType<T>(role, propertyRef);
    }

}
```

---

GenericBagType:

```
public class EnhancedGenericBagType<T> : BagType
    {
        public EnhancedGenericBagType(string role, string propertyRef) :
            base(role, propertyRef, false) { }

        public override IPersistentCollection Instantiate(ISessionImplementor session, ICollectionPersister persister, object key)
        {
            return new EnhancedPersistentGenericBag<T>(session);
        }

        public override IPersistentCollection Wrap(ISessionImplementor session, object collection)
        {
            return new EnhancedPersistentGenericBag<T>(session, (ICollection<T>)collection);
        }

        public override Type ReturnedClass
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(ICollection<T>);
            }
        }

        protected override void Add(object collection, object element)
        {
            ((ICollection<T>)collection).Add((T)element);
        }

        protected override void Clear(object collection)
        {
            ((ICollection<T>)collection).Clear();
        }

        public override object Instantiate(int anticipatedSize)
        {
            if (anticipatedSize > 0)
                return new List<T>(anticipatedSize + 1);
            else
                return new List<T>();
        }
    }
```

---

How to override default CollectionTypeFactory:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.CollectionTypeFactory<EnhancedCollectionTypeFactory>();
```